# SQL Concat Values from second table into one column

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have two SQL tables

Entries(entryid,name,date)

Entry Files(fileid,entryid,filename,dateadded)

Im trying to write a stored procedure to return everything from Entries and for each row a concatenated list of the files for that entry.

from reading through stack overflow ive got as far as this

```
SELECT *,
        (
            SELECT f.FileName + ','
            FROM EntryFiles f 
            WHERE f.entryid = e.entryid
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ) AS Files
FROM Entries e
```

Im getting duplicate rows for the rows that have files, I know im doing something really stupid but having a brain dead moment.
Cheers

For Example I Get

entryid    name     date          files

1          entry1   01/01/2012    NULL

2          entry2   01/02/2012    file1, file2,

2          entry2   01/02/2012    file1, file2,

Comment: Looks good to me. Please add some sample data that shows the issue you have.

Comment: For Example I Get
entryid    name     date          files
1          entry1   01/01/2012    NULL
2          entry2   01/02/2012    file1, file2,
2          entry2   01/02/2012    file1, file2,

Comment: Do you have duplicate `entryid` in table `Entries` ? What you have works just fine. Have a look here: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/62758/new

Answer (score 1):

use distinct keyword...hope this will help u..

Answer (score 1):

try this I hope you will get the solution

```
SELECT *,
        (
            SELECT f.FileName 
            FROM EntryFiles f 
            WHERE f.entryid = e.entryid
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ) AS Files
FROM Entries e
```